# Android: Send a signal from a thread in execution

Tags: android, multithreading, signals, messaging

**Situation**: I make a call to a thread, which in turn pings a server with a serialized object. Immediately after that, a function call pings the server with some parameters.

**Problem** : The thread indeed get ***called*** before the function, but the function finishes execution before the thread does. Result is that the parameters are sent before the serialized object.

**How do I make the function not start its execution, until the thread has finished ? In other words, can the thread send a "signal" that its finished, so that I can begin execution of the remainder of the code ?**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a book example of a situation where `CountDownLatch` should be used. Indeed, if you go to the [documentation page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) you'll find a example of what you seem to need (I mean the `CountDownLatch(1)` example).